# XML schema complexType within an complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

I am writing XSD for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="WS.xslt" ?>
<interface name="WS">
    <package>com.example</package>
    <import>java.rmi.RemoteException</import>
    <import>java.io.*</import>
        <abstract_method name="login">
            <modifier>public</modifier>
            <arguments>
                <parameter type="int">id</parameter>
                <parameter type="String">pass</parameter>
            </arguments>
            <return>boolean</return>
        </abstract_method>
        <abstract_method name="send">
            <modifier>private</modifier>
            <arguments>
                <parameter type="String">subject</parameter>
                <parameter type="String">message</parameter>
            </arguments>
            <exceptions>
                <exception>IOException</exception>
                <exception>RemoteException</exception>
            </exceptions>
            <return>void</return>
        </abstract_method>
</interface>
```

My current XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name ="WebServiceInterface">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name ="package" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name ="import" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:complexType name ="abstract_method" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs= "unbounded">
        <xsd:element name ="modifier" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:complexType name="arguments">
            <xsd:element name ="parameters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs= "unbounded"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name ="exceptions">
            <xsd:element name ="exception" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name = "return"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Error Message:

> "S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'sequence' Must
>   Match (annotation?, (element | Group | Choice | Sequence | Any)*). A
>   Problem Was Found Starting At: ComplexType."

How do I include the interface without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either (solution 1) wrap the `<xsd:complexType>` in an `<xsd:element>` or (solution 2) define the `<xsd:complexType name="...">` elsewhere and refer to it with an `<xsd:element type="...">`. complexType is aimed at defining a content model, for any element you want to create (and type). Solution 2 is sometimes preferable because it allows you reuse (as-is, or extend, or restrict) content models you define.

**Examples:**

*For solution 1:*

```
  <xsd:element name="interface">
    <xsd:complexType>
       [... definition of the complexType ...]
```

*For solution 2:*

```
  <xsd:complexType name="WebServiceInterface">
       [... definition of the complexType ...]
```

**Finally:**

Thus you may correct your schema that way:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="interface" type="WebServiceInterface"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="WebServiceInterface">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="package" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="import" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="abstract_method" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="modifier" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="arguments">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="exceptions">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="exception" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="return"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'return'. One Of '{exceptions}' Is Expected.. Line '11', Column '13'.

Comment: looking at the code you kindly offered, I don't see any problems with the return element and it seems to match up with the XML so may I have some advice on the above error Please?

Comment: It's because of your input XML: `<abstract_method name="login">` is lacking the `<exceptions>` tag. If `<exceptions>` is optional, you should change the schema with: `<xsd:element name="exceptions" minOccurs="0">`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this error without including exceptions tags as the first method is not suppose to include exceptions?

Comment: Yes, there is - see the former comment.

Comment: I am sorry that I am quite confused what did you mean by former comment? Do you mean the answer you provided?

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it now. Sorry I got confused a little. Because my element already had minOccurs but it was my complexType exception that was missing. Thank you so much!